# CSS-Center alignment for image in a carousel ng-repeat

Tags: css, image, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, carousel

I am using carousel for image display but I would like to cater it for all types of image dimension a user upload. I resized all images before displaying it in a carousel but i cant seem to make in into center. I have tried **margin:auto** / **text-align:center** either in the **li** tag or **img** tag but it doesn't seem to work for me. Below are some samples of the carousel showing empty spaces and the image should be displayed in the center.

**Image restrained by width**
[image: Image restrained by width]

**Image restrained by height**

[image: Image restrained by height]

What i wanted to achieve here is to make the images to display in the center either it is restrained by width or height. This is how my images are rendered

```
<div class="fanpageCarousel" ng-controller="FanCarouselCtrl"
ng-init="getImage()">
<ul rn-carousel rn-carousel-indicator rn-carousel-auto-slide="3"
    rn-carousel-pause-on-hover="true">
    <li ng-repeat="image in slides"><img ng-src="{{image.src}}" /></li>
</ul>
```

And these are my CSS customization

```
.fanpageCarousel{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 450px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.fanpageCarousel img{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5r8jkk56/) link

Hope someone can give me some assistance.. Thank You

Comment: Are you able to create a JSFiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @HiddenHobbes here's the JSFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/5r8jkk56/  As you can see if I add images of different dimension, you will have blank spaces here and there... what I wanted to do is to put all these different images in the center to make it looks more presentable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Make the following changes to CSS:**

```
.fanpageCarousel img {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.fanpageCarousel li {
    height: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

In short the container (`li`) around each `img` needs to be set to `position: relative;` to allow the `img` to be positioned relative to it. `Height` needs to be specifically set on the `li` for this to work. `text-align: center;` is a fallback for older browsers to at least center the `img` horizontally. Setting `position: absolute;`, `margin: auto;` and `bottom`, `left`, `right` and `top` to `0` is what makes the `img` center in the `li`.

**JS Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/h82ajq0c/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help mate... Your explanations had guided me for my following implementation of these carousel galleries... cheers mate.. have a good day :)